# show that $\lim_{z \rightarrow −i}\frac{\Im(z)}{\bar{z}}=i$ .

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Using the definition of limits, I want to show that $\lim_{z\rightarrow -i}\frac{\Im(z)}{\bar{z}}=i$.

This is how far I got.

$\left|\frac{\Im(z)}{\bar{z}}-i\right|=\left|\frac{\Im(z)-i\bar{z}}{\bar{z}}\right|=\frac{\left|\Im(z)-i\bar{z}\right|}{\left|\bar{z}\right|}=\frac{\left|\Im(z)-i\bar{z}\right|}{\left|z\right|}=\frac{\left|\Im((z+i)-i)-i(\bar{z}-i+i)\right|}{\left|z\right|}=\frac{\left|\Im(z+i)-\Im(i)-i(\bar{z}-i)+1)\right|}{\left|z\right|}=\frac{\left|\Im(z+i)-i(\bar{z}-i)\right|}{\left|z\right|}=\frac{\left|\Im(z+i)-i(\overline{z+i})\right|}{\left|z\right|}\leq \frac{\left|\Im(z+i)\right|+\left|-i(\overline{z+i})\right|}{\left|z\right|}\leq \frac{\left|z+i\right|+\left|z+i\right|}{\left|z\right|}=\frac{2\left|z+i\right|}{\left|z\right|}=\frac{2\left|z+i\right|}{\left|(z+i)-i\right|}$

Then I wanted to use the reverse triangle inequality to bound the denominator

$\frac{2\left|z+i\right|}{\left|(z+i)-i\right|}\leq \frac{2\left|z+i\right|}{\left|\left|z+i\right|-\left|i\right|\right|}=\frac{2\left|z+i\right|}{\left|\left|z+i\right|-1\right|}$

and this is where I got stuck, I can't see how I can bound this from above using $\delta$

Note: I know the easiest would be to use the fact that the function is continuous and just do a substitution, but I need to do this with the definition. Also, I'd like not to use cartesian or polar forms.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It will be much easier to write $z=a+bi$ with $a,b$ real and $\Im(z)=b,$ and $\overline z=a-bi.$

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, in the meantime I edited the question, because I forgot to say that I's like to do this without Cartesian or polar forms.

Comment: Let $\delta < 1/2$.  You'll be able to show $$||z+i|-1| = 1 - |z+i| > \tfrac12,$$ which should make the final result easier.

Comment: If, $w=\overline z,$ then $\Im(z)=-\Im(w),$ so you can write this as: $$-\lim_{w\to i} \frac{\Im(w)}{w}.$$

Comment: Of course, $z\mapsto \Im(z)$ and $z\mapsto \overline z$ are continuous functions, and the second converges to a non-zero value as $z\to -I,$ so...

Comment: Thank you very much both! @BrianMoehring, awesome, that's what I was looking for!